# Android Studio not recognizing setter and getter

Tags: android, android-room, setter, getter

I've been trying to use Room to read from an SQLite database and it's been constantly giving me errors about not being able to find getters and setters for the data object's class even after I've used Android Studio's auto generated getters and setters for the fields.

I'm also getting the error: error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor.

Here is my code:

```
package mergerobotics.memo.backend.Room;
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;


@Entity(tableName = "competitions")
public class CompetitionsEntity {

    @NonNull

    @PrimaryKey
    private String mId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "competition")
    private String mCompName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "year")
    private String mCompYear;

    public CompetitionsEntity(String Id, String CompName, String CompYear){
        this.mCompName = CompName;
        this.mCompYear = CompYear;
        this.mId = Id;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getmId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setmId(@NonNull String mId) {
        this.mId = mId;
    }

    public String getmCompName() {
        return mCompName;
    }

    public void setmCompName(String mCompName) {
        this.mCompName = mCompName;
    }

    public String getmCompYear() {
        return mCompYear;
    }

    public void setmCompYear(String mCompYear) {
        this.mCompYear = mCompYear;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your empty constructor?

Comment: Here is the constructor 
```public CompetitionsEntity(String Id, String CompName, String CompYear)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the variable names in the parameters of constructor to match the variables names declared in the class above.
Your constructor should look like:

```
public CompetitionsEntity(String mId, String mCompName, String mCompYear){
        this.mCompName = mCompName;
        this.mCompYear = mCompYear;
        this.mId = mId;
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Install Lombok plugins in your Android Studio by the following stesp :

```
File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Search Lombok
```

Install the plugins and restart IDE